# How to add member name in MDX query

Tags: mdx, olap, olap4j

I have just started to work with OLAP Cubes. I have some questions about MDX queries. I have a query like:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Balance].[NegEXPENSE] AS '-[Balance].[Type].[EXPENSE]' 
SET BalanceTypeSet AS {[Balance].[Type].[INCOME], [Balance].[NegEXPENSE]} 
MEMBER [Balance].[TypeSum] AS AGGREGATE(BalanceTypeSet) 
SELECT {Measures.[Sum]} ON COLUMNS, 
{[Balance].[Type].[INCOME], [Balance].[Type].[EXPENSE], [Balance].[TypeSum]} ON ROWS 
FROM [Balance Cube]
```

The result of this query like:

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOd49.png)

This result doesn't have a name of the last row(TypeSum). How can I add a name for TypeSum?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add calculated dimension member, try this:

```
WITH 

MEMBER [Balance].[Type].[TypeSum] AS AGGREGATE(BalanceTypeSet) 

SELECT {[Measures].[Sum]} ON COLUMNS, 
{[Balance].[Type]} ON ROWS 
FROM [Balance Cube]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this query haven't worked. I have an exception which is 'Mondrian Error:Internal error: The '[Balance].[All]' calculated member cannot be used as a parent of another calculated member.'.

Comment: Try with update. Never worked with Mondrian, SSAS only and using calculated dimension members is pretty typical scenario.

Comment: I added a calculated dimension member in schema.xml file which has the cube. This calculated dimension member is the negative of [Balance].[Type].[EXPENSE]. When I added this member to my query, I didn't have an exception but calculated member name does return from the result.

Comment: Yes, I tried to see all members with this query: `SELECT {Measures.[Sum]} ON COLUMNS, {[Balance].Members} ON ROWS FROM [Balance Cube]` and then I didn't see the calculated dimension member at the result.

Comment: Is there AllMembers function available? In SSAS Member will not return calculated dimension member, while AllMember will.

Comment: It is not like SSAS. I couldn't work allmembers correctly.